# Mutt: do not execute send-hook for aborted unmodified messages

Tags: email, mutt

I use two identities in Mutt (say, `this@server.tld` and `that@server.tld`), and for one of those (say, `that@server.tld`) I need a `Bcc` header to be added automatically to all outgoing messages. I have managed to do this using a `send-hook` as per the instructions at https://mutt-users.mutt.narkive.com/6D8d7dmp/adding-a-bcc-in-a-send-hook:

```
send-hook '~f ^that@server.tld$' 'push <edit-bcc>bcc@address.tld<enter>'
```

This solution works *almost* perfectly in the sense that the `Bcc` header is added to saved drafts while on the 'compose' screen; however, if I:

- start replying to a message sent to `that@server.tld` from the 'index' screen and
- then close the unsaved draft,

Mutt still executes the command from the `send-hook` (i.e., `push <edit-bcc>bcc@address.tld<enter>`) on the currently selected message that I was originally replying to. In other words, after aborting the draft message the source of the original message is opened automatically in the text editor instead of the 'index' screen to be shown.

So, how do I prevent `send-hook`s to be executed on aborted messages?

Thanks.